# input and span elements with tooltip within div in same line

Tags: html, css

The span element in div has a tooltip. When I remove the tooltip from the span, see second div (word), the input field moves a bit higher than rest of input fields.

How can I fix this issue? Thank you in advanced.

```
    <div>
        <div class="word">
            <input id="word-4" name="word-4" type="text" data-index="3" value="the">
            <span class="x-tag" value="4"></span>
            <span class="tooltip" value="4"><span class="tooltiptext">Words</span>&gt;&lt;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="word">
            <input id="word-5" name="word-5" type="text" data-index="4" value="supermarket">
            <span class="x-tag" value="5"></span>
            <span class="" value=""></span>
        </div>
        <div class="word">
            <input id="word-6" name="word-6" type="text" data-index="5" value="nerby">
            <span class="x-tag" value="6"></span>
            <span class="tooltip" value="6"><span class="tooltiptext">Words</span>&gt;&lt;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the full example:

[https://jsfiddle.net/myFiddler/5encgkh0/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/myFiddler/5encgkh0/)

Comment: In which browser?

Comment: in Firefox. Hiren hast the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `float:left from input`, there is no need to use and give padding to parent element

```css
/***************/
/* Tool-Tip   */
/***************/

/*https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp*/

.parent{
  padding:25px;
}

.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    /* border-bottom: 1px dotted black; If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
    visibility: hidden;
 width: 120px;
 margin-left: -60px;
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
 border-radius: 6px;
 
 /* Fade in tooltip - takes 1 second to go from 0% to 100% opac: */
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity 2s;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; /* At the bottom of the tooltip */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

/********************/
/***  Word Input  ***/
/********************/

.word {
    width: 141px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
 margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.word .no-linking {
 cursor: auto;
}
.icon-link.checked {
 color: rgb(255,120,90);
}

.word > input {
    width: 100px !important;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px !important;
}

span.word {
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.icon-link {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-top: 6px;
 padding-left: 3px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.x-tag:after {
    font-size: 13px;
    content: "x";
    padding: 1px 2px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 100;
    right: 36px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
   <div class="word">
    <input id="word-1" name="word-1" type="text" data-index="0" value="I">
    <span class="x-tag" value="1"></span>
    <span class="tooltip" value="1"><span class="tooltiptext">Words</span>&gt;&lt;</span>
   </div>
   <div class="word">
    <input id="word-2" name="word-2" type="text" data-index="1" value="go">
    <span class="x-tag" value="2"></span>
    <span class="tooltip" value="2"><span class="tooltiptext">Words</span>&gt;&lt;</span>
   </div>
   <div class="word">
    <input id="word-3" name="word-3" type="text" data-index="2" value="to">
    <span class="x-tag" value="3"></span>
    <span class="tooltip" value="3"><span class="tooltiptext">Words</span>&gt;&lt;</span>
   </div>
   <div class="word">
    <input id="word-4" name="word-4" type="text" data-index="3" value="the">
    <span class="x-tag" value="4"></span>
    <span class="tooltip" value="4"><span class="tooltiptext">Words</span>&gt;&lt;</span>
   </div>
   <div class="word">
    <input id="word-5" name="word-5" type="text" data-index="4" value="supermarket">
    <span class="x-tag" value="5"></span>
    <span class="" value=""></span>
   </div>
   <div class="word">
    <input id="word-6" name="word-6" type="text" data-index="5" value="nerby">
    <span class="x-tag" value="6"></span>
    <span class="tooltip" value="6"><span class="tooltiptext">Words</span>&gt;&lt;</span>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. That makes sense due to it is invisible.

Comment: @toye glad it helped